# Is there a way to generate WMI code/classes?

Tags: c#, code-generation, wmi

How do you generate C# classes for accessing WMI?

Answer (score 8):

To generate strongly typed WMI classes, use the Management Strongly typed class generator (MgmtClassGen.exe).  It's usually in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio X\SDK\vX\Bin.  The parameters are [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa.aspx) and they even have [a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186156.aspx) describing the code generated.  If you have to do a lot of work with WMI, it's a lifesaver.

Comment: on more recent setups where the SDK is separate the path is a little different e. g. `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft sdks\windows\v8.0a\bin\NET FX 4.0 Tools`

Comment: @MikeBaz and @VanOrman - see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/is-there-a-way-to-generate-wmi-code-classes/44506#comment-60961898) - do you know perhaps how to use it with `Visual Studio 2015`?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\mgmtclassgen.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\mgmtclassgen.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\mgmtclassgen.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\mgmtclassgen.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\mgmtclassgen.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\mgmtclassgen.exe"

Answer (score 7):

**Easier approach (Visual Studio users):**

1. Add WMI classes to VisualStudio's Server Explorer.  E.g.

   [image]
2. Get Visual Studio to call [MgmtClassGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa.aspx) for you.  E.g.

   [image]

@VanOrman provides additional [references for MgmtClassGen.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44506/939250).

Comment: Sorry for commenting 2+ years later - I was occupied searching how to use the underlying tool, the `MgmtClassGen.exe` in `VS`. such a shame, 2+ years were wasted. Since I don't have the `Management Classes` entry under my machine, maybe do you have an idea how to add it to `VS2015`? I suppose I should have the `MgmtClassGen.exe` somehow connected under the hood for that...? (the [Management (WMI) Extensions for Visual Studio .NET 2003 Server Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10483), as its name suggests, is not for `Visual Studio 2015`)

Comment: Any idea how to get this menu item in vs 2019? I see the event logs tree and such in Server Explorer and MgmtClassGen.exe is on my machine but I don't see the nice UI

Answer (score 2):

You can try WMICodeCreator it generates vbscript jscript vb.net and c# code
[Download WMICodeCreator from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)