# WMI C# Server accepts RDP connections

Tags: c#, wmi, terminal-services

We have 6 Citrix Servers. I'm trying to find out if Remote Logons are enabled/disabled.

I plan to put this onto of a webpage to display and green icon if they are or red if they aren't.

I've managed to connect to the machines and pull operating system information etc.. However when i try and connect to view the TerminalServiceSetting information.. i get an Invalid Class error.

Here is my code.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\MACHINENAME\\ROOT\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

//create object query
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM     Win32_TerminalServiceSetting");

//create object searcher
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

//get collection of WMI objects
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

//enumerate the collection.
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    // access properties of the WMI object
    Label1.Text = m["AllowTSConnections"].ToString();
}
```

If anyone can shed some light on it that would be great.

Thanks

Update:

I have now found the code (i think) that checks to see if remote connections are enabled or disabled.

```
ManagementScope scope =
    new ManagementScope("\\\\MACHINENAME\\root\\CIMV2\\TerminalServices",con);
scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
scope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
scope.Connect();



//create object query
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_TerminalServiceSetting");

//create object searcher
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

//get collection of WMI objects
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

//enumerate the collection.
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{

    if (m["AllowTSConnections"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        Redicon.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Greenicon.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

However when i run the code i get returned "1".. which is fine. However if i deny remote logins on the server and re run the code it stays at 1..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that the server provide the TerminalServiceSetting information. WMI uses unmanaged code because not all servers and their configurations provide all information.

You can use [Mgmtclassgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa.aspx) to generate managed code and at the same time make sure that the server provides the information.

Comment: Considering the server is a Citrix Server.. wouldn't that provide the TerminalServer information?

However i will try this.

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/is-there-a-way-to-generate-wmi-code-classes

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!!!

I was looking up the wrong field.

the correct one is :

```
Label1.Text = "Remote Connections: " + m["Logons"].ToString();
```